# What are the equivalent types for FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor & FunctionScoreFunction in 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Upgrading from NEST 1.6.2 to 2.3.3.

What are the new types for `FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor` and `FunctionScoreFunction` in NEST 2.3.3?

Are they  `FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor` -> `ScoreFunctionsDescriptor` and
`FunctionScoreFunction` -> `ScoreFunctionsDescriptor`?

If that's the case, we build a `var functionScores = new List<Func<ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<IndexData>, ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<Property>>>()`, but how do we pass this down to

`var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<IndexData>()
                .Paged(pageable)
                .Query(q => q
                    .FunctionScore(fs => fs.Functions(***How do we pass the functionScores***));`

Can we build it like below?

`functionScores.ForEach(f => searchDescriptor.Query(q => q.FunctionScore(fc => fc.Functions(f))));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `function_score` query can take either an `IEnumerable<IScoreFunction>` or a `Func<ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<T>, IPromise<IList<IScoreFunction>>>` i.e. a function that takes a score descriptor and returns a list of functions. A `ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<T>` implements `IPromise<IList<IScoreFunction>>`

Based on this, if we want to aggregate a bunch of functions together, we can aggregate over a bunch of functions that take a `ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<T>` and return a `ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<T>`

```
public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public GeoLocation Location { get; set;}
}

var functions = new List<Func<ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<Document>, ScoreFunctionsDescriptor<Document>>>
{
    s => s.FieldValueFactor(fvf => fvf
        .Field(f => f.Name).Weight(3)),
    s => s.ExponentialGeoLocation(geo => geo
        .Field(f => f.Location)
        .Offset("1km")
        .Origin(new GeoLocation(-33.87189, 151.21623))
        .Scale("2km")
    )
};

client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .FunctionScore(fs => fs
            .Functions(sc => functions.Aggregate(sc, (a,f) => f(a)))
        )
    )
);
```

which in this example yields

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "name"
          },
          "weight": 3.0
        },
        {
          "exp": {
            "location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": -33.87189,
                "lon": 151.21623
              },
              "scale": "2.0km",
              "offset": "1.0km"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```